# angularJS, real time on $http get JSON and check method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, angularjs, real-time

I have a Json object made by RoR method in a controller, sending a Json with a Time.

The database is fill often by a smartphone. The RoR application build the Json file and my angular Service is charged to get this Json via $http.

My question is:
Can I have a realtime in angularJS checking if there is new data in my DB without refreshing the page, charging the new data in the Json ?
For example, my application with the Time of the object is stocked in the DB, I would like to display the value if the Time is under 30 minutes ago from now. If not, i don't display the point. When I load the application, it's okey, it works, but now I want real time on this method or something who check every second if the Time is outdated (>30minutes ago) or still available.

Is there a solution for that, and if you have some tips how to implement it ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try using the $timeout in angular in order to poll the data from your server on a regular basis (like 30 minutes or less in your case)

As it was not possible to create an example without your data, and I didn't want to stay 30 minutes in order to see if it worked, I made you this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/mgSWt/3/ , it simulates the query of data ( what you do with $http ) and then analyze it in order to display only the items within the time limit

To be more precise,  I create 3 variables at the beginning of the controller, corresponding to the time the page loaded, one, and two minutes before (but it's easy to pass it to 30 minutes) :

```
var n=new Date()
var onemin=n.getTime()-60*1000//one min from now
var twomin=n.getTime()-60*1000*2//two min from now
```

After that, I create a function to get the data ( with your example, I think it could be better with a service, but that's another question). This function will get the whole data (at least hard code it in my example) and check which items are to show or not. Then I call this function , and the function itself schedule the next execution time, on my example, every second (what you should set to another value, 30 min, less, it will depend on your application) :

```
$scope.updateData=function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        //$http.get('/your/url').success(...).error(...)
        //you should get your data here, but I just force it for the example
    $scope.rawData=[{"time":n.getTime(),"content":"The value created when the page loaded"},
                 {"time":onemin,"content":"The value was created one minute before the page load"},
                 {"time":twomin,"content":"The value was created two minute before the page load"}];
    console.log($scope.rawData)
    var whatTimeIsIt=new Date();
    $scope.data=Array()//erasing any previous data
    $scope.notShown=Array();//for the test
    for(var i in $scope.rawData){
         if($scope.rawData[i].time>(whatTimeIsIt.getTime() - 90*1000))//checking each value time, if there was more than 1 min 30 sec or not
            {
                $scope.data.push($scope.rawData[i]);
            }
        else
            {
                $scope.notShown.push($scope.rawData[i])
            }
    }
    //at the end of the function, we populated $scope.data with all the object with a time less than 1min 30 ago
        $scope.updateData();//schedule the next update
    }
,1000);
}
$scope.updateData();
```

The code is just for this precise example, so you will have to adapt it, but the concept works. On the HTML side, you can, of course, show the values, which I did in two parts for the example, the data which should be shown ( within the time limit ) and the data which would have been skipped ( > time limit )

```
    Values that should be shown : 
    <div ng-repeat='values in data'>
        {{values.time}} : {{values.content}}
    </div>
    <br/>
    Values outdated :
    <div ng-repeat='values in notShown'>
        {{values.time}} : {{values.content}}
    </div>
```

If you watch the console, you can see every call to the function, every second.

In this example I set 1min30 for the time limit, so the 2 first objects will be on the displayed list for 30 second, the 31 seconds later, only the first will be shown for another 1 minute, and then all of them should be hidden/deleted/sent to mordor/whatever you want

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Do you think I can use the $watch of angular?
I have a method giving me the status of the item when I get the Json file, I'm calling this method in my ng-repeat, and for each items of the Json, if it's under 30 min, i'm sending true, else false. This method use an another method, creating a date.now and checking the date of the Json with this Date.now. (both are timestamp)

So could I use a $watch to change the getStatus method of an item or using a timeout is mandatory?

Thanks by advance

Comment: The timeout here is just for the example, as you wanted to wait 30 min, but it could be $watch or an event. For example, you could totally call the `updateData` function within a $watch, it would recalculate the data to show/hide on each modification. Actually, if you delete the timeout parts on the function, you can call it like any other function, bind it to an event or call it in a $watch

Comment: If you want an example, I modified a bit the fiddle in order to watch a variable ( which I modify with a button, but your timestamp would be fine) : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/mgSWt/4/ . You can click on the button, it will make the variable change, the $watch see the modification, then call the update data function. The timings are the same, if you wait 30s after the page load and click, the second item will move to the no-show list =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a timeout to execute the [list](https://blog.pusher.com/making-angular-js-realtime-with-pusher/) function.